# Computing a local parameter: don't understand a step

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, zariski-topology

In trying to compute a local parameter of some projective curve, this paper I am reading uses the fact that if ${C_Z}$ is an affine variety, then the inclusion (which is a morphism) ${i : C_Z\hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^2(k)}$ induces a surjection of local rings ${\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^2(k),i(P)}\twoheadrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{C_Z,P}}$. I can't see why this is true. Given a rational function ${r}$ that's regular at $P$ in ${C_Z}$, I've tried producing a rational function ${r'}$ that's regular at ${i(P)}$ in ${\mathbb{A}^2(k)}$ such that ${r'\circ i = r}$, but I can't seem to do this. Any help?

Comment: This is the definition of a closed immersion (plus potentially some basic facts on sheaves).  How much familiarity do you have with the concept of closed immersions?

Comment: @KReiser I haven't heard of this term before. Is there no simple way to see that this induced map on local rings is surjective? I will add in detail my current attempt if that helps

Comment: Simple depends on your background. (For me, what I wrote is very simple.) Can you provide more details about your background and what "simple" would mean for you?

Comment: @CoffeeBean: any regular function on an affine variety is induced by a regular function on affine space by the definitions. And any rational function locally is equal to the quotient of two regular functions, which implies that the same holds for germs of rational functions.

Comment: @danneks I think I've managed to reason with myself why it's true now. Would you be able to check the answer I posted?

Comment: @CoffeeBean: I think that your argument is correct.

Comment: @danneks Cool, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I think I managed to figure it out based on the comment left by @danneks. So let ${i : X\to \mathbb{A}^2(k)}$ be the inclusion of the variety $X$ into ${\mathbb{A}^2(k)}$. An element $r$ of the local ring ${\mathcal{O}_{X,P}}$ is a regular function on a neighborhood of $P$; call this neighborhood ${\mathcal{U}}$. Then $r$ is really just an open cover of ${\mathcal{U} = \bigcup_{i \in I}\mathcal{U}_i}$ together with rational polynomial functions ${r_i}$ such that ${r_i = r_j}$ on ${\mathcal{U}_i\cap \mathcal{U}_j}$ for any ${i,j}$.

$P$ must belong to at least one of these open sets in the cover, so let ${\mathcal{U}_t}$ be as such. By definition of the subspace topology, ${\mathcal{U}_t = \mathcal{U}_t'\cap X}$ for some open ${\mathcal{U}_t'\subseteq \mathbb{A}^2(k)}$. Also, ${r_t}$ must be regular on some open set ${\mathcal{U}_* \subseteq \mathbb{A}^2(k)}$, and it must be the case that ${\mathcal{U}_t = \mathcal{U}_t'\cap X \subseteq \mathcal{U}_*\cap X}$ (since ${\mathcal{U}_*}$ is the largest open set of ${\mathbb{A}^2(k)}$ for which ${r_t}$ is regular). So let ${f = [(\mathcal{U}_*,r_t)] \in \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^2(k),i(P)}}$. Then
$$
f\circ i = [(\mathcal{U}_*\cap X,r_t)] = [(\mathcal{U}_t'\cap X,r_t)] = [(\mathcal{U}_t,r_t)] = r
$$
The last equality comes from the fact that ${r_t}$ ends up agreeing on the intersections.